# I can't see mysql database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, gridview, datasource

I downloaded the following dlls:

- mysql.data.dll
- mysql.data.cf.dll
- mysql.data.entitity.dll
- mysql.web.dll

and added to references in Visual Studio 2010, but when I want to use gridview, I cant see mysql database.

Comment: Show us your code. We can't guess what's wrong..

Answer (score 3):

i think you are missing a using statement for some namespace (most likely mysql.data or mysql.data.client)

you should have a look at 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html